# HTML5 Canvas - adding an image to ctx

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I thought I'd have a little play around with Canvas animations, as I've not really done much with it before. So I forked [this repo](https://github.com/DaNmarner/Flapcopy)

[Live demo](http://danmarner.github.io/Flapcopy/)

and decided my first stop would be to replace the 'red rect' with an image. Should be pretty straight forward I thought. So I'll just replace the `ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);` with a new `Image()`

For some reason, the image never appears.

Here is my Bird.draw method.

```
Bird.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
  ctx.fill();
  
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'images/icon.jpg';
  base_image.onload = function(){
      console.log('loaded');
      ctx.drawImage(base_image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      return ctx.fillText("" + this.score + "/" + this.highest, this.x, this.y - 2);
  }
 
};
```

[and a full working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3wA9/1/)

I've also tried swapping out he image.load for a pattern, but it still didn't load.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I find between your code and working code on a project I have is that I assign the url to image's src **after** defining image onload listener.

```
this.canvas.loadImage = function (image, x, y, w, h) {
        var context = this.getContext("2d");
        var myImage = new Image();
        myImage.onload = function () { context.drawImage(myImage, x, y, w, h); };
        myImage.src = image; //<-- only actual difference I see with your code
        return myImage;
    }
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

`this` inside an image.onload refers to the image (not Bird) so your this.x & this.y are undefined.

**Solution**

Attach a reference to your Bird to your base_image:

```
base_image.Bird=this;  // this is your Bird
```

So here some refactored code (not tested--some tweaking may be required!):

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
ctx.fill();

base_image = new Image();

base_image.Bird=this;

base_image.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Choice_toxicity_icon.png';

base_image.onload = function(){

   ctx.drawImage(base_image, 
       this.Bird.x, this.Bird.y, this.Bird.width, this.Bird.height);

   ctx.fillText("" + this.Bird.score + "/" + this.Bird.highest, 
       this.Bird.x, this.Bird.y - 2);

}
```

**Second Problem**

The draw function is being called repeatedly.  Therefore you're loading the image repeatedly and causing these bad effects depending on how fast the browser can load each new smileyface:

- In IE11 the smileyface remains on the page
- In FF27 the smileyface initially appears on the page but disappears on mouse movement
- In Chrome32 the smileyface **is loaded and drawn** but disappears immediately

**Second Solution**

Pull the image loading out of draw() and just do drawImage(mySavedSmileyFace) inside draw().

Comment: hmmm. couldn't get that to work, even tweaking my x,y,w,h, to be hardcoded values: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3wA9/12/

Comment: Your revised code actually is successfully loading the smileyface in IE,FF & Chrome.  However your draw() function is being called repeatedly and that's causing additional problems.  See my edited answer ;)  BTW, nice snow-image on your profile icon...reminds me of my years in snowy Minnesota, USA!